# MLE of fourth moment of normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Take $X\sim N(0,\theta)$, and let $\phi = E(X^4)$, the fourth moment. What is its MLE, $\hat{\phi}$, and what is the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\phi} - \phi) $ as $n\to \infty$? Any help with this question would be appreciated, as I really can't think of where to start!! Many thanks.

I have integrated the expression for $E(X^4)$ by parts three times to get $\phi = 6\theta^3$, which gives $\hat{\phi} = 6\hat{\theta}^3$ as the function is continuous (is this correct?). However, I am not sure what the MLE of $\theta$ should be, and what that makes the asymptotic distribution $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\phi} - \phi) $.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Comment: Sure, I have done so. Thanks for your comment, this is my first time on the site.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this should exercise some common sense and rescind that vote.  It's just newbie-biting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean $\theta=\operatorname E(X^2)$.

The fourth moment is
$$
\operatorname E(X^4) = 3\theta^2.
$$
If you can find the MLE $\hat\theta$ for $\theta$, then the MLE for $3\theta^2$ is just $3\hat\theta^2$.  Something useful to know about MLEs is that if $g$ is a function, and which function $g$ is does not depend on any parameters being estimated, then the MLE of $g(\alpha)$ is $g(\hat\alpha)$ where $\hat\alpha$ is the MLE of $\alpha$.

(The asymptotic distribution is something I'll look at later.  Probably the delta method will work.)

**PS:** I see you're saying you got $6\theta^3$.  Having a third power there doesn't make sense.  Let $\varphi$ be the standard normal density, so the standard distribution is
$\varphi(x)\,dx$.  Then the $N(0,\theta)$ distribution (assuming you mean by that that the variance, not the standard deviation, is $\theta$, is
$$
\varphi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\theta}}\right)\,\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\theta}}.
$$
So
\begin{align}
\operatorname E(X^4) & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^4 \varphi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\theta}}\right)\,\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\theta}} = \theta^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^4}{\theta^2} \varphi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\theta}}\right)\,\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\theta}} \\[10pt]
& = \theta^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty u^4 \varphi(u)\,du = \theta^2 \operatorname E (Z^4)
\end{align}
where $Z\sim N(0,1)$.  So it has to be proportional to $\theta^2$.

**PPS:**  OK, let's look at the integral
\begin{align}
& \phantom{={}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^4\varphi(z)\,dz = 2\int_0^\infty z^4\varphi(z)\,dz \\[8pt]
& = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty z^3 \exp(-z^2/2)\Big(z\,dz\Big) \\[8pt]
& = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty \sqrt{2w\,{}}^3 \exp(-w)\,dw \\[8pt]
& = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{2}^3\Gamma(5/2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{2}^3\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac32\cdot\Gamma(1/2) \\[8pt]
& = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\sqrt{2}^3\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac32\cdot\sqrt{\pi} \\[10pt]
& = 3.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, I see where I went wrong in the integral, and your reasoning that it has to be proportional to $\theta^2$ makes sense too.